# "File is not responding" Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, nautilus, wayland

my Nautilus randomly crashes and it does all the times I use the search bar looking for a file or for a folder, I just need to type a letter and it is gone.
The message I get is "File is not responding", but sometimes it gives up working "silently".

The searching feature works smoothly if I'm browsing files/folders to be attached to a mail message or in Whatsapp.

I need to kill the nautilus process and run:

```
~$ nautilus refresh
```

to have it working again.

Everything works fine if I use KDE desktop (but...) and I have already disabled Wayland.

Thanks